# How to use Laravel IMAP for receive mailbox?

Tags: laravel, email, imap

I am using laravel imap package for email setup for receive mailbox.

use this https://github.com/Webklex/laravel-imap#installation package, but i don't understand how it works or test. If anybody for help ?

Comment: As mention in https://github.com/Webklex/laravel-imap#configuration. You need to configure at .env file. You need to have one email SMTP server, in this case you can use your Gmail account as SMTP for testing.

Comment: How can I see my recieve mail? Please help

Comment: Please setting your Gmail account as SMTP server first.
Try this bro: https://artisansweb.net/sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-server-laravel/

Comment: I don't tell email send, i tell email receive.

Comment: You can hardcode information and use `Mail::send` function follow this tutorial: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#sending-mail

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have already **installed** the package and set your environment variables in .env

Here is an example of how to get all unseen messages from Inbox. (check the API Docs for more available methods or classes)
https://github.com/Webklex/laravel-imap#documentation

```
$oClient = Client::account('default'); // defined in config/imap.php
$oClient->connect();

// get all unseen messages from folder INBOX
$aMessage = $oClient->getUnseenMessages($oClient->getFolder('INBOX'));

foreach ($aMessage as $oMessage) {
    // do something with the message
}
```